# Easy way to create movie DVDs? DVDStyler QDVDAuthor DeVeDe No Go

Tags: dvd

I've been trying to create a movie DVD with some authoring tools after having split out my vid/aud/sub through avconv.

- After reading through the many man pages and website tips, editing xml files for DVDAuthor looks to be too much a pain.
- QDVDAuthor seems to have collected development/support dust and require libavcodec-extras-52 which I can't get installed.
- DVD Styler seems to go nowhere with an enigmatic Error Menu Creation before rudely crashing. Anyone have a better suggestion?
- DeVeDe complains it seems a bug in mencoder at any attempt to create something.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple other alternatives you can try:

- [Bombono DVD](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/bombono-dvd/) - It seems that some users report that it cannot be run from the Unity dash, however the terminal command `bombono-dvd` will open it once installed.
- KDE's [KMediaFactory](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/kmediafactory/) - This installs and runs fine for me, and like all other KDE software, it seems to be quite complete in design and runs fine. You will have to install all the KDE base libraries, but if you're not concerned about disk space that will not be a problem.
- [Mistelix](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/mistelix/) - This seems to be more targeted towards users desiring to create homemade slideshow-type projects, but it may achieve your goal anyway.
- [Tovid GUI](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/tovidgui/) - It has been described as "archaic". However, upon installation it seems that this is probably the most complete and feature-rich software available for the intended purpose. You will be presented with a plentiful array of options. However, this is also meant to be run from the terminal, with the command `tovid gui`.

Comment: Have you used any of these? Do you have any advice on using them successfully?

Comment: I edited my answer to include more information and formal research. However, I have not used any of the programs in a practical situation.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>(I had the same problem, and I must admit that *full of bugs* is a qualificative that applies to most of DVD software, so I can understand that `DeVeDe` and `DVDAuthor` are still a no go)</sub>

To complete the already existing answer, now with ubuntu 13.10 and later, **DVDStyler** runs fine and perfectly answers our problem. However I must point out that some of the other softwares are dead projects.

- DVDStyler still in active development ([SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dvdstyler/)),
- DeVeDe remained unchanged/unmaintened since 2012 ([GitHub](https://github.com/rastersoft/Devede)),
- DVDAuthor died in 2012 too. ([SF](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dvdauthor/files/)).
- Bonobo-Dvd could probably do the job but I never used it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's any help,
but the SNAP store (from software)
can install Open DVD Producer with:

```
sudo snap install opendvdproducer --channel=edge
```

It seems to be focused on producing video DVDs
with menus and all.

Answer (score 0):

#### Bombono DVD

Bombono DVD (*bombono-dvd*) is an easy to use program for making DVD videos. Imported videos can be loaded into a timeline and previewed frame by frame. What's more, the software allows you to split each video into multiple chapters. All you have to do is create one or more key points on a video's timeline, which can be done with a single click. A chapter's length can be modified just by clicking and dragging the created key points.

The main features of Bombono DVD are:

- excellent MPEG viewer: Timeline and Monitor
- real WYSIWYG Menu Editor with live thumbnails
- comfortable drag-and-drop support
- You can author to folder, make ISO-image or burn directly to DVD.
- reauthoring: You can import video from DVD disks.

Bombono DVD works great in 18.04, but not in 19.04. To install it open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install bombono-dvd bombono-dvd-data
```

---

#### Open DVD Producer

Open DVD Producer (*opendvdproducer*) is a modern, open source cross platform software to produce DVD images, and create DVDs with menus and chapters in a simple yet professional way. The main functions of the DVD specification are implemented in the software. For example, you can create a DVD in any supported format, with various menus, with directional buttons, videos with chapters and set sections of videos to play.

The main features of Open DVD Producer are:

- **Menus** - You can create static menus with any sound you want. Or you can use some special video as animated menu.
- **Buttons** - "Point and click" the buttons you want to create, and you have a real time preview of them. Also, you can set the directions the remote control will take.
- **Built-in encoder** - There is no need to use some external conversor. Open DVD Producer is able to convert from any kind of known video format.
- **Chapters** - Want to play at some point in the video? No problem, you can set chapter marks directly on the timeline, and also set segmented pieces of video.
- **MD5 checksum** - Generate MD5 after the ISO is ready for integrity check.
- **DDP® for replication** - The DDP® can be generated for large production (specification version 2.00).
- **Advanced settings for menus** - You can set the background image or video. The color and opacity of buttons highlight. Set the buttons directions directly on the screen.
- **Advanced settings for videos** - It is possible to set the video resolution. Also you can set chapter marks in a visual way, with frame-by-frame accuracy.

To install Open DVD Producer in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap install opendvdproducer --channel=edge
```

---

#### DVDStyler

[DVDStyler](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dvdstyler/) is a cross-platform free DVD authoring application that makes possible for video enthusiasts to create professional-looking DVDs. DVDStyler provides over 20 DVD menu templates, allowing you to create your own menu designs and photo slideshows. After you select your DVD label name, video quality, video format, aspect ratio, and audio format, you can select a template to add video materials to. DVDStyler's interface supports drag-and-drop so you can add project buttons and movies around with ease. Some basic video editing operations such as trimming and cropping are also available.

The main features of DVDStyler are:

- create and burn DVD video with interactive menus
- support of AVI, MOV, MP4, MPEG, OGG, WMV and other file formats
- support of MPEG-2, MPEG-4, DivX, Xvid, MP2, MP3, AC-3 and other audio and video formats
- user-friendly interface with support of drag-and-drop
- flexible menu creation on the basis of scalable vector graphics
  file

To install DVDStyler dwonload the DVDStyler .tar.bz2 file and follow the instructions in [How do I install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](https://askubuntu.com/q/25961/).